# Is there a property to "autobind" or "rebind" a select again in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-value

I need to update the items in a `select` using Angular JS.

The initial data in the `select` is good (using `ng-repeat`), but it will change depending of another parameter value, the `ng-repeat` works in the first load, but when the data changes (JSON) the `select` shows the initial data and not the new data.

My question is not about how to bind it using JavaScript because I know how, my question is if exists a property that update the items like `ng-model`, which update the value of the input when the property associated changes.

Thanks.

Comment: You can look at [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead of using `ng-repeat`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan but the select is on a modal, it will work?

Comment: Depends on a lot of things. Try it and see.

Comment: doesn't works.. do you have an example?

Comment: The link in my original comment is to the documentation, which has many examples. You can also search on the internet and here on SO for many more examples.